# Reusing a view model but applying different validation rules in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, viewmodel

So we use DataAnnotations to achieve input validation for our ASP.NET MVC forms. If we were to start again I'd consider Fluent Validation, but we're too far along now to make the change.

So this project requires us to build a lot of forms. As we've progressed, we've identified groups of inputs that get repeated across forms. An example of this might be a set of inputs to represent an Address.

We've then turned the Address input into a reusable module by creating an `_AddressEntry` partial view for it along with an associated view model - `AddressViewModel`. The view model for the parent form then looks like:

```
public class SubmitEnquiryViewModel
{
    public AddressViewModel Address { get; set; }

    public string Enquiry { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

In the `_SubmitEnquiry` view, we then insert the `_AddressEntry` partial view using `EditorFor()`.

This works fine until we realise different instances of the Address input have different validation requirements - the validation attributes decorating `AddressViewModel` do not always apply. To get around the problem we define an `IAddressViewModel`:

```
public interface IAddressViewModel
{
    string LineOne { get; set; }

    string LineTwo { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And then define concrete implementations of this interface for all the different permutations of validation specification - e.g. `AddressViewModel` (default validation), `AddressNoValidationViewModel` etc.

The `_AddressEntry` partial view is then bound to `IAddressViewModel` and the appropriate concrete implementation is chosen for the Address property of the parent view model.

The main drawback of this approach is that we could potentially end up with quite a few view models that only differ by the validation attributes applied to them. This is deemed acceptable though as the number of reusable modules is expected to be relatively small.

Has anyone else faced this challenge before? What solution did you come up with? What are your thoughts on the solution described above?

Comment: How are you doing your validations, exactly?

Comment: Using OOTB `DataAnnotations` validation attributes and letting `DefaultModelBinder` do its thing (and thus `DataAnnotationsModelValidator` I guess).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [MetadataTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.metadatatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Base class:

```
public abstract class AddressDetailsBase
{
  public string Line1 { get; set; }
  public string Line2 { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string State { get; set; }
  public int PostalCode { get; set;}
}
```

Validation (I use interfaces so it can't be accidentally instantiated):

```
public interface IUserAddressDetailsValidation
{
  [required]
  string Line1 { get; set; }
  [required]
  string Line2 { get; set; }
  [required]
  string City { get; set; }
  [required]
  string State { get; set; }
  [required]
  int PostalCode { get; set;}
}
```

View Model Type:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(IUserAddressDetailsValidation))]
public class UserAddressDetails : AddressDetailsBase { }
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing MetadataTypeAttribute to my attention.

This solution works apart from one issue - binding the view to AddressDetailsBase, the HTML helpers don't pick up validation attributes applied in IUserAddressDetailsValidation so client side validation doesn't work. Any ideas?

I'm trying to dynamically change the parameter type of the expression passed in to the HTML helper from AddressDetailsBase to UserAddressDetails but I'm struggling at the moment!

Comment: In this instance you would not use the Base object for validation, it has no validation.  As for the struggle with changing it, I can't help you as you haven't provided any details what so ever.

Comment: The fundamental issue has been identified here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15232767/3619572 I have resolved the issue by using the non generic HTML helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Data Annotations are good for very simple scenarios and for prototype projects.
As you can see, you are already fighting the annotations, which are not suited to work in different contexts.

Just use plain ModelState.AddModelError in controller actions, and build custom validation logic in your controller.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Prop", "Your custom 'validation failed' message.");
```

You can still evaluate `ModelState.IsValid` before doing your custom validation, so you can still use DataAnnotations for simple cases for some code reuse.