# How to bind a model dynamically to a view based on user input asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc I need help to bind a different model to the view from what was originally sent to the view.

Let me explain it further

I have a Model like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UI.Data.Models.Claim.Shared.CustomerInfo;

namespace UI.Data.Models.Claim
{
    public abstract class CreateClaimViewmodel 
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public UserFirstName UFname { get; set; }        

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
   public CustomerAddress CustProvidedAddress { get; set; } 


    public List<Transactions.Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public DiscrepancyType discreType {get; set;}
     public List<IDiscrepancy> discrepancy  { get; set; } // assumption

 }
```

}

I have noted Idiscrepancy as an interface as this might be a different child class based on what the user selects on this view. So when the user selects a discrepancy type from one of the dropdown list values a partial view pops up which has corresponding questions for that discrepancy type. All these discrepancy types point to different Models/ partial views in my application

```
 public enum DiscrepancyType
    {
        WithdrawalError,
        DepositError,
        CancelDetails,
        CanceledServiceSubscTransac,
        DuplicateTransaction,
        ChargedInsteadOfCredit,
        CreditNotReceived,
        DefectiveMerchantdise,
        DifferentAuthorizedAmount,
        GoodsServicesNotReceived,
        MerchandiseReturned,
        NotAsDescribed,
        PaidByAnotherMethod,
        TransacNotRecognized,
        UnauthorizedTransaction, // many more 

    }
```

Here comes my question

The part works fine where I want to display a partial view based on the drop down. But I understand now when I post it back to the controller , the new object of type that has been added to the View ( of Idiscrepancy property) based on the users selection from a drop down is not bind to the Model as the Model doesnt exist anymore.  How do I tell my controller that use this new model instead of the Old one ?

I tried using Jquery , but for each partial view I need to write  different jquery code and also create json objects . Is there an efficient way where I can tell my controller that I am posting a view with the same model , but an added object of type  . There are 24 classes of that use/ implement idiscrepancy.

Another option that I thought was using a @model Dynamic , but I am not really sure if that would help my scenario

I understand this is pretty common at many companies and I wonder why there is not much documentation about dynamically changing models based on user input.

Please apologize if my terms are incorrect as I am still trying to get out of webforms thinking.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot use an interface as a model. The first step in binding is that the `DefaultModelBinder` creates an instance of your model (internally using `Activator.CreateInstance()`).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether i have understood your question correctly, but if you want to implement a functionality where each discrepancy type has to load its list, then one way of implemention is to use [knockoutjs](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections). It has this two way binding which automatically changes the model data when you change the drop down. It would load the values of the List. You have to create a similar ViewModel like CreateClaim in the script side.

I have done a similar kind of functionality in my application, where a change in the district loads it district related information. I had only one model.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using Knockoutjs ? :(

Comment: As Steve mentioned you cannot use an interface in the model and you need to recreate the model. Also you might need to create a discrepancy common base class which is used in the model and binded to the view. There was a similar discussion happened in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897206/using-an-interface-as-the-model-type-of-a-partial-view-data-annotations

Comment: Yes I agree that I cannot use Interface , that's y i mentioned it as an assumption. I already looked at the other question as a part of my search and it did not have an answer. I can use a common base class but still that  I do not know how to use that base class to bind the model at run time because a model doesnt exist then.

Comment: Have one Base class model, which have get set properties of all the discrepancy types model. Bind the view to the base class model and in the view render each partial view using Html.RenderPartial("_nameofView", Model.DiscrepancyType1Model); Here the keyword Model refers to the base class model and DiscrepancyType1Model is the name of the getter proprety referenced to that model. On change of value in dropdown, fetch the values from the controller action of the baseclass type model and load the values of the model.